Error de permisos en directorios usados por Docker y aplicación que estoy desarrollando
Esta pregunta busca resolver un problema con una herramienta de programacion e implementada en la programacion y mediante programacion (Docker).
Estoy Ejecutando un contenedor docker mysql desde mi propio desarrollo (una aplicaciones en C#) y configuré la persistencia de datos en esta ruta:
C:\ProgramData\Persistence\data\mysql
Cuando inicio todo va bien porque no hay datos (primera ejecución)

Una vez que comienzo a desarrollar (crear base de datos... etc.) y por alguna razón reinicio la PC y abro nuevamente Docker-Desktop e inicio el contenedor, ya no funciona...

He logrado determinar que el problema son los permisos del directorio, el atributo de solo lectura (todavía estoy investigando por qué...):

He investigado y he intentado solucionarlo con los siguientes métodos:
de CMD: icacls "C:\ProgramData\Persistence" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /T
formulario PowerShell: Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Persistence" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.Attributes -= "ReadOnly" }
Estos comandos se ejecutaron con mi usuario personal con privilegios de administrador activos y ejecutando CMD y Powershell con privilegios de administrador.
pero el problema persiste... y no puedo encontrar una manera programática o una forma en el archivo YML para resolverlo, que es mi único interés...
Log Content:
2024-04-15 16:31:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
2024-04-15 16:31:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-04-15 16:31:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': Permission denied
2024-04-15T16:31:39.941325Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-04-15T16:31:40.118455Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2024-04-15T16:31:40.123899Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.3.0) starting as process 1
2024-04-15T16:31:40.127250Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2024-04-15T16:31:40.128854Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-04-15T16:31:40.129566Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.3.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-04-15T16:31:40.129575Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.

He comprobado que cambiando el atributo de forma manualmente se soluciona, pero no es lo que busco.
Actualización 1
Probé algunos cambios en mi archivo YML y en mi archivo Dockerfile:
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./log/mysql:/var/log/mysql:rw

and
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/mysql
RUN chmod -R 0755 /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql /etc/mysql

Mi expectativa es que algo como esto funcione, pero nada de esto funciona.
Actualización 2
He estado evaluando y por alguna razón el problema está relacionado con cómo funciona Docker y la estructura de directorios... y la interacción con software de terceros...
El problema se produce de la siguiente manera:

una vez que Docker está activo por primera vez con los contenedores y el contenido de MySQL, todo va bien...
Si por algún casual otro software o herramienta de terceros utiliza o ingresa a la ruta donde se encuentran los datos de persistencia, estos.
Cuando reinicias el sistema deja de funcionar correctamente. como si entre la aplicación de terceros y el reinicio pasara algo con los permisos…suena tonto pero parece que algo pasa en ese momento.

Este es mi script de Powershell
Me gustaría pensar que hay una manera de solucionar el problema de forma nativa, desde el yml o dockerfile con los que se construye la estructura y el entorno docker/container, pero hasta el momento no lo he solucionado... por eso para solucionar el problema, cada vez que esto ocurre, se debe ejecutar manualmente este script en PowerShell (repito esto no es lo deseado):
# Define the path to the directory
$directoryPath = "C:\ProgramData\Persistence"

# Get the current ACL (Access Control List) for the directory
$acl = Get-Acl $directoryPath

# Define the permission rule to grant full control to everyone
$permission = "Everyone", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"

# Create a new access rule
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission

# Add the access rule to the ACL
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)

# Set the ACL for the directory
Set-Acl -Path $directoryPath -AclObject $acl

# Check if the permissions were applied successfully
Get-Acl $directoryPath

Entonces:
Aunque este script resuelve el problema una vez iniciado/detectado pero de forma manualmente, no es la forma que esperaba resolverlo, todavía estoy buscando una forma que prevenga esta situación.

yo tengo exactamente el mismo problema con uno de los archivos de configuracion. Lo que hago todas las mañanas, es renombrarlo, ejecuto el compose, docker crea un archivo, y luego apago todo, borro el nuevo archivo, renombro para atras, y todo se soluciona magicamente.. el problema es docker en windows, que de alguna forma, deja tomado el archivo...

exacto el docker es un trolaso XD el tener que hacer un workaround para resolver un comportamiento no deseado ... para mi es un bug ... pero en el sitio principal dice que no ... porque no es el paradigma con el que se debe usar ...

segun el foro de docker... y los usuarios haya... ellos esperan que cada dia al final de tu trabajo, puedas comitear todo a un repositorio y destruir (Borrar/Desintalar) todo el entorno de docker/contenedores ... para que al dia siguiente desde un archivo, debas levantar todo el entorno... la persistencia de estructura / configuraciones no esta pensada en docker ... jajajajaja solo el punto de partida desde un archivo YML ...

para mi esto supone problemas... por que no se trata de desarrollos de un solo dia ...

no.. eso no es cierto.. los volumenes es correcto que sigan vivos.. yo igual al final del dia apago la pc, asi que todo se fue.. y por lo menos en mi caso, son archivos de configuracion...

para mi en este caso es la base de datos como tal ...

@gbianchi me estoy viendo forzado en agregar esto ... https://i.imgur.com/SAo2D6b.png digo imaginate que tu tengas la opciond e crear un script en powershell que con un boton/tarea programada se ejecute ... para mi no es lo correcto...

@gbianchi de casualidad has intentado darle el owner al usuario que necesitas que tenga acceso al archivo que mencionas??? en mi caso seria algo como: RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql desde el Dockerfile

voy a implementarlo y hacer pruebas XD
